# DDR3 1866 for Mobo that support 1600 only

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr

i am unclear on this point 
if the Mobo says it support only 1333/1600, no o/C mentioned, 
but has XMP support

will 1866 work at all?

if so, will it work at 1866 or 1600?

i am asking because i found several places where 1866/9 is cheaper than 1600/9

thanks

Comment: The bios should clock it back to1866, no guarantees though.

Comment: The high rates are mostly the same memory with different timings different voltages sometimes, not all that special, many of them have normal SPD profiles available  With the higher rate falling under XMP profiles.  So if you have a motherboard or CPU that does not support , it is likely to work only at the lower rates and will work fine usually.  Issue that can come from that is if it does not have lower rate timings, it would be a tiny bit slower, with timings that could have run at higher rate.

Comment: At any rate :-) it probably is not on the compatability list for the motherboard, so I would concider that your first  possible flaw.  If at all possible finding ram that is on the compatability list is more sure to work and without any issues, as it has been tested to do so.

Comment: Unless you are looking at a price premium for the slower memory and/or can't find it, get the slower memory, if you get memory that runs at the supported frequency, your chances of it working, increases to nearly 100%